# On phone drawer(menu) open listener

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there a way to listen to the phone menu button click.
for example when ever the phone menu(drawer) opens to show a toast that it opened.

Comment: See this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html There is `onDrawerOpened()` method.

Comment: No man this is for the widget,i want to listen to the phone menu.